# how to put space between two images side by side in overleaf?

Tags: spacing, subfloats

i wanted to put 2 image side by side and the last one at the bottom . I managed to do this by this code:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
  \subfloat[Subcaption 1]{\label{figur:1}\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{complex/chapter5/pos1.jpg}}
  
  \subfloat[Subcaption 2]{\label{figur:2}\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{complex/chapter5/pos2.jpg}}
  \\
  \subfloat[Subcaption 3]{\label{figur:3}\includegraphics[width=1.1\textwidth]{complex/chapter5/scanning.PNG}}
  \label{figur}\caption{equation...}
\end{figure}
```

However, there is a problem. I cant put space between them. width of the upper image and bottom image should be equal to textwidth. How can I achieve that?

in the meantime, I am also having a caption with double parenthesis `(())` instead of single `()`. In the picture, you can have a look.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was reducing the width of the graphics and manually adding some `\hspace`.

I wasn't able to reproduce your double-parentheses captions; they came out normal for me running the following code:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
  \subfloat[Subcaption 1]{\label{figur:1}\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{a.jpg}}
  \hspace{.1\textwidth}
  \subfloat[Subcaption 2]{\label{figur:2}\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{b.jpg}}
  \\
  \subfloat[Subcaption 3]{\label{figur:3}\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{c.PNG}}
  \label{figur}\caption{equation...}
\end{figure}
```